# How do I split a video every X minutes?

Tags: video, imovie

How can I split a video every X minutes using iMovie or some other Mac software, outputting the split videos to a folder, named by section (e.g. "video1of4", "video2of4")?

Comment: I'm super interested in this script too '@trying_hal9000 I'll work on adding the 5 min skip for you, I'm not sure why the splits would all be different lengths, obviously wrote this 5 years ago so would have to do some testing for you - glad you like the script. – @Deesbek May 31 '18 at 8:01" Is it ready/working at the moment?
Thanks

Comment: @Dim the `interval=120` line controls the section length; 120 seconds is 2 minutes. Assuming the script works today, change the line to `interval=300` for five minute long sections.

Comment: @Dim I asked this question 9 years ago. I don't even remember why I asked it.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use [-f segment](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment) with ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -f segment -segment_time 300 -reset_timestamps 1 %03d.mp4
```

`-c copy` disables re-encoding video and audio, like `-vcodec copy -acodec copy`. `-reset_timestamps 1` makes each segment start with a near-zero timestamp.

Answer (score 4):

### Split a video with VLC from the command line

Open Terminal and run the following script:

It determines the length of the original file and splits it into 2 min intervals.

You can change this by changing the `$interval` variable, which is in seconds.

You will also need to change the `$filename` variable to whatever file you want to split.

```
#!/bin/bash
filename=test.mkv
duration=`ffprobe -show_format $filename | sed -n '/duration/s/.*=//p'`
duration=${duration/.*}
interval=120
start=0
n=$start
stop=$interval
while [ $duration -ge 0 ]; do
    /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC -Idummy $filename --start-time $start --stop-time $stop --sout=#file{dst=$n-out-$filename} vlc://quit
    let start=stop
    let stop=stop+interval
    let duration=duration-interval
    echo "Number of seconds left to process: $duration"
    let n=n+1
done
```

Comment: This script has been tested with vlc 1.1.3 and 2.2.1

Comment: Thank you! this is about to be my favorite thing ever! One quick question, why are the split files all slightly different lengths? They vary about 4-10 seconds? (I have interval set to 180 which I thought would be 3min each, however, on average they are all closer to 4min long)

Comment: Hey would there be a way to modify this script so that it would split the interval time (say 2minutes) and then skip 5minutes forward before spliting the next 2minutes? So split 2min, skip 5min, split 2min, skip 5min, split 2min, so on and so forth? many thanks!

Comment: @trying_hal9000 I'll work on adding the 5 min skip for you, I'm not sure why the splits would all be different lengths, obviously wrote this 5 years ago so would have to do some testing for you - glad you like the script.

Answer (score 3):

QuickTime Pro does a great job using the Trim feature. It's intuitive too.

Answer (score 0):

VLC has an "Exporting Wizard" that will let you subset. VLC also has a CLI interface so you should be able to automate it.

Comment: More content, such as actual instructions of the GUI and/or CLI interface, would be grand.

Answer (score 0):

I used to do splits using ffmpeg on Fedora . I don't have the exact command handy though.

You could install ffmpeg and mplayer tools on OS X .

Answer (score 0):

## Movie Splitter

If you are splitting `mpeg4` movies and prefer a graphical application, you can use [Movie Splitter](https://miln.eu/moviesplitter/). I wrote the application to split my movies by chapter marker but duration based splitting is supported:

> - Automatically by chapter marker
> - Into two halves
> - Into four quarters
> - Into unlimited custom sections
> - Into regular durations; 1 second to multi-hour sections

[image: Movie Splitter on macOS]